# check for item in a list

Tags: python-3.x

check for item in a list
check for item in a list
check for item in a list
check for item in a list

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want but here goes:

```
from itertools import permutations 
s = ['8','role','lore','pre','erp','elor','orle','rep']
res = []
anag = set()
for x in s:
    if x in anag:
        continue
    res.append(x)
    for per in permutations(x):
        anag.add(''.join(per))
res = sorted(res)
#['8', 'role', 'pre']
```